# User session is getting interrupted after approx. 45 seconds

Tags: r, session, shiny, shiny-server, reconnect

I have the shiny application deployed on the `Rshiny pro server(1.5.2)`.

Application does some heavy computations and generates the report without any problem if it gets completed before approximately `45 seconds`.

If the computation and report generation goes beyond approximately 45 seconds, user's session / connection to the server is getting interrupted. Then automatically server is `reconnecting` the disconnected users almost immediately. After few seconds of `re-connection` the user session is getting reaped and user is presented with the notwork error.

From above observations we know that the `reconnect` flag is `enabled` at the server.

I need help to understand-

1. Why the user session is getting interrupted around approximately `45 seconds` every single time.
2. How to prevent this session interruption? Is there any configuration at server or application side which will help me achieve uninterrupted session between user and server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after searching and trying out different options I was able to find the answers to my questions.

1. The user session was getting interrupted around approximately 45 seconds every single time because the `http_keepalive_timeout` parameter was not defined in the `server configuration` and the `default value` for `http_keepalive_timeout` parameter  is `45 seconds`.
2. To prevent the session from getting reaped before the report generation,  I **added** the `http_keepalive_timeout` parameter to the `shiny-server.conf` at the `top level` and set it's value to `120 seconds` as shown below.

   http_keepalive_timeout 120;

You can set the `http_keepalive_timeout` value as per your wish. I set it to `120` as my application is taking around `100-110 seconds` to generate the report.

**Reference:** [shiny server configuration](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/)
[image]

Comment: Hi Abhinandan, where do you put the `http_keepalive_timeout 120;` ? When I try to put it in my shiny-server.conf file, it gives me an error resetting the server saying it cannot configure correctly. Please see my SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520166/updating-shiny-server-config-to-change-timeout-error

Comment: @Kevin. Sorry, I just saw your comment. I think you got the solution. Let me know if any help needed.