# R shiny downloadHandler returns a network error after a short duration

Tags: r, shiny, ondemand

The issue I'm encountering has been discussed here on [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/197). The problem I'm having is that, after a short period of time (~45-90sec), the downloadHandler returns a network error instead of the plot.png that is expected. Sometimes the download link will work but it's hit or miss. The shiny app is deployed on an Open onDemand HPC setup. From the shared discussion, the advice is to add `http_keepalive_timeout 600;` to the shiny-server.conf file. My problem is that I'm not aware of any shiny-server.conf file. The shiny-server docs says the file is located at `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server. conf`. Can anyone tell me how to find this file? I have very little experience with app deployment and the engineer who deployed the app for me is not aware of any such file/location.

Comment: If your Shiny Server is on Ubuntu, it is at `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`. You will need access to edit this file. Related to this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300285/user-session-is-getting-interrupted-after-approx-45-seconds/45318121#45318121